# Setting custom header with API gateway non-proxy lambda and binary output

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, lambda, api-gateway

Is it possible to set a custom header when using lambda non proxy integrations?

At the moment I have enabled binary support and I am returning straight from my handler but I have a requirement to set the file name of the download and was planning to use `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.xlsx"` but I am not sure how I can do this if I have lambda proxy integration turned off.

Reading this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html I am not sure if it only works for json responses?

The example shows the body comment as taking a json object but then says there is a base64 encoding option for binary support, but I am just returning my binary data straight from my function and I had not planned to use lambda proxy at all if possible.

I currently have files downloading but I am using temporary files and I want to name the downloads.

```
# In my service 
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".xlsx") as tmp:
    pd.DataFrame(report_json).to_excel(tmp.name)

    bytes_io = BytesIO(tmp.read())

    return bytes_io

# In my handler
return base64.b64encode(bytes_io.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using later versions of the serverless framework a custom header for example `Content-Disposition` can be set like the following.

```
Integration: lambda
response:
  headers:
    Content-Type: "'text/csv'"
    Content-Disposition: "'attachment; filename=abc.csv'"
```

I am not sure yet if it is possible to interpolate values from the context into these values.